# An upper bound on the rate of convergence of a series with a variable starting index

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $a, b, k_0$ be fixed real numbers, of which $a$ and $b$ are strictly positive. Is there some non-negative real number $c$ such that, for large enough $n$'s,
$$
\sum_{k = k_0 + \sqrt{\frac{a}{b} \ln(n)}}^\infty e^{-b (k - k_0)^2} \leq n^{-c}
$$
where the sum starts at the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to $k_0 + \sqrt{\frac{a}{b} \ln(n)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the case $a=b=1$ and $k_0=0$, so that we have
$$
\sum_{k=\sqrt{\ln(n)}}^{\infty}e^{-k^2}.
$$
If we define $a_k:=e^{-k^2}$, then
$$
\left\lvert\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right\rvert=e^{-(k+1)^2+k^2}=e^{-2k-1}.
$$
So, in particular, for any given $m$,
$$
\left\lvert\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right\vert=e^{-2k-1}\leq e^{-2m-1}\leq e^{-2m},\qquad k\geq m,
$$
and therefore
$$
\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}e^{-k^2}\leq \sum_{k=m}^{\infty}e^{-m^2}(e^{-2m})^{k-1}.
$$
This is a geometric series, with first term $e^{-m^2}e^{-2m(m-1)}=e^{-3m^2+2m}$, and common ratio $e^{-2m}$; so, as long as $\lvert e^{-2m}\rvert<1$ (and it is), 
$$
\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}e^{-m^2}(e^{-2m})^{k-1}=\frac{e^{-3m^2+2m}}{1-e^{-2m}}.
$$
Here, we are taking $m$ to be the least integer such that $m\geq\sqrt{\ln(n)}$. For $n$ sufficiently large and $m\geq\sqrt{\ln(n)}$, it is certainly true that $e^{-2m}\leq\frac{1}{2}$, and therefore $1-e^{-2m}\geq\frac{1}{2}$; hence $(1-e^{-2m})^{-1}\leq\frac{1}{2}$ for such $m$, and we get
$$
\frac{e^{-3m^2+2m}}{1-e^{-2m}}\leq\frac{1}{2}e^{-3m^2+2m}.
$$
For $m\geq 1$ (which is certainly true for sufficiently large $n$ here), it is also certainly true that $m\leq m^2$, so that $-3m^2+2m\leq-m^2\leq-\ln(n)$. So, we get
$$
\sum_{k=\sqrt{\ln(n)}}^{\infty}e^{-k^2}\leq\frac{1}{2}e^{-\ln n}=\frac{1}{2n}.
$$

You can of course modify this proof throughout to cover the extra constants; you can also be a bit sneakier here and there and use some changes of variables / algebra to rewrite in more convenient forms.  But, this should at least give you the idea!